# How to I set the login screen resolution or scaling in Kubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, kde, plasma-5

I have a 4K display that is hard to read when at boot/login screen. Once I login, it seems to automatically scale, as the scale appears to be 1x in the system settings. Is there any way to copy or force that display setting on KDE before logging in?

I'm using the built-in display on a Quattro mobile card. It's a Dell Precision 9550 iirc.

Comment: are you using graphics card? is it a primary display or secondary display 4k?

Comment: primary display, built in to laptop and yes using gfx with prop nvidia quattro drivers